# Agregar valores de un propiedad de un objeto a otro a traves de funcion map

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto, map

tengo el objeto foo y quiero enviar solo los skills al array result mediante la funcion map. No se como ejecutarlo a traves de map

```
let foo = {
    id:100,
    name:"foo",
    role:"admin",
    skills:["javascript", "html", "css", "python", "flask", "react", "redux"]
};
let result= [];

let niu = Object.values(foo).map(function(){
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la siguiente forma compañero:

```javascript
let foo = {
        id:100,
        name:"foo",
        role:"admin",
        skills:["javascript", "html", "css", "python", "flask", 
                "react","redux"]
    };

    let result= [];
    
    
    foo.skills.map((skill, index) => result[index]=skill)

    console.log(result)

// output
// Array (7): 
// ["javascript", "html", "css", "python", "flask", "react","redux"]
```

> Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map